# Как пропарсить JSON файл в Swift data

Tags: json, парсер, swift

Есть JSON файлы от с такой структурой. 818, 819,820 и т.д. - номера солов(дней) меняются ежедневно.

```
{
   "818":{
      "First_UTC":"2021-03-15T20:01:49Z",
      "Last_UTC":"2021-03-16T17:32:54Z",
      "Month_ordinal":12,
      "Northern_season":"late winter",
      "PRE":{
         "av":727.696,
         "ct":109855,
         "mn":710.223,
         "mx":743.946
      },
      "Season":"winter",
      "Southern_season":"late summer",
      "WD":{
         "most_common":null
      }
   },
   "819":{
      "First_UTC":"2021-03-16T17:32:59Z",
      "Last_UTC":"2021-03-17T18:12:29Z",
      "Month_ordinal":12,
      "Northern_season":"late winter",
      "PRE":{
         "av":730.402,
         "ct":100681,
         "mn":709.8325,
         "mx":744.4856
      },
      "Season":"winter",
      "Southern_season":"late summer",
      "WD":{
         "most_common":null
      }
   },
   "820":{
      "First_UTC":"2021-03-17T18:12:34Z",
      "Last_UTC":"2021-03-18T18:52:04Z",
      "Month_ordinal":12,
      "Northern_season":"late winter",
      "PRE":{
         "av":728.2,
         "ct":88500,
         "mn":709.7541,
         "mx":741.3344
      },
      "Season":"winter",
      "Southern_season":"late summer",
      "WD":{
         "most_common":null
      }
   },
   "821":{
      "First_UTC":"2021-03-18T18:52:09Z",
      "Last_UTC":"2021-03-19T19:31:39Z",
      "Month_ordinal":12,
      "Northern_season":"late winter",
      "PRE":{
         "av":729.649,
         "ct":88777,
         "mn":710.0807,
         "mx":744.1994
      },
      "Season":"winter",
      "Southern_season":"late summer",
      "WD":{
         "most_common":null
      }
   },
   "sol_keys":[
      "818",
      "819",
      "820",
      "821"
   ],
   "validity_checks":{
      "818":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               8,
               9,
               10,
               11,
               12,
               13,
               14,
               15,
               16,
               17,
               18,
               19,
               20,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":true
         }
      },
      "819":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               8,
               9,
               10,
               11,
               12,
               13,
               14,
               15,
               16,
               17,
               18,
               19,
               20,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":true
         }
      },
      "820":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               9,
               10,
               11,
               12,
               13,
               14,
               15,
               16,
               17,
               18,
               19,
               20,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":true
         }
      },
      "821":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               8,
               9,
               10,
               11,
               12,
               13,
               14,
               15,
               16,
               17,
               18,
               19,
               20,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":true
         }
      },
      "822":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               8,
               17,
               18,
               19,
               20,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":false
         }
      },
      "823":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6,
               7,
               8,
               9,
               21,
               22,
               23
            ],
            "valid":false
         }
      },
      "824":{
         "PRE":{
            "sol_hours_with_data":[
               0,
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6
            ],
            "valid":false
         }
      },
      "sol_hours_required":18,
      "sols_checked":[
         "818",
         "819",
         "820",
         "821",
         "822",
         "823",
         "824"
      ]
   }
}
```

Создана структура:

```
struct SolData: Decodable {
    let season: String?
    let PRE: PRE?
    
    struct PRE: Decodable {
        let av: Double?
        let mn: Double?
        let mx: Double?
    }
}
```

Далее

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let urlString = "https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=DEMO_KEY&feedtype=json&ver=1.0"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let safeData = data else { return }
            guard error == nil else { return }
        //some code here
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Что именно вызывает сложность? Структура для части ответа правильная. Другие части нужны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте строку вместо //some code here:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(SolData.self, from: safeData)
```